# submitting form with two buttons

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 buttons in HTML form. And both of them should submit the form. I would need to capture which button has been clicked so i can use it to perform different actions based on which button was clicked.

I am able to submit the form with both the buttons but how would i capture which button was clicked in the php file .

```
<INPUT  type="button" name="submit" class="button" class="element_2" value="firstbutton">
<INPUT  type="button" name="submit1" class="button" class="element_2" value="second button.. ">
```

i am using post method in Jquery to submit the form. How can i check which HTML button was clicked  in server side php script

Comment: You might want to add why you need two submit buttons. A simple radio button seems like would also work and you would have a true submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hidden element here, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="submittedBy" name="submittedBy">
```

Your current [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler using [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) should work, just update the hidden field when clicking either button, for example:

```
$("form :submit").click(function() {
  $("#submittedBy").val(this.name);
});
```

Then in PHP just check that `$_POST["submittedBy"] == "submit"` or `"submit1"` to see which caused it.

---

The alternative is to have the `click` handler POST and add in the value between [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and when [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) is called, like this:

```
$("form :submit").click(function() {
  var data = $(this.form).serializeArray();
  data.push({ name: 'submittedBy', value: this.name });
  $.post("myPage.php", data, function(result) {
    //do something
  });
  return false; //prevent normal form submission, even with the .submit() handler
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this,

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" name="action[update]" value="1">Update</button>
<button type="submit" name="action[delete]" value="1">Delete</button>
```

**PHP**

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']['update']) ? 'update' : 'delete';
```

You CAN'T depend on JavaScript to tell you wich button was clicked, if user has JavaScript disabled, your form is broken.

Comment: If you have more than two, the same logic applies, but you migh want to use a switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the isset function

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "first button was clicked";
}
```

Or to detect the second one was clicked:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
echo "second button.. was clicked";
}
```

Comment: See @Nick comment on my deleted answer as to why this is wrong.

Comment: @Darin - 53 rep ;) I'll repro here though.

Comment: This isn't correct, he's using the post method in jQuery, even if using `.serialize()`, it explicitly outlines this doesn't happen: "Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Data from file select elements is not serialized." Reference: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @Nick Thanks for pointing out the reason why Darin's earlier solution would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would capture all the events on the page using:

```
$(document).click(function (obj) {
    if ('equipmentSetup' === obj.target.id) {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
```

....

Then add an if statement looking for the "id" of the button you want. Don't use the name or id "submit". I forgot why but I remember it caused problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the buttons to type="button" and give them ids. With that, you can use the jquery line (not able to check my syntax below, but think i've got it right)

```
$('form button').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') = "button1"){ ...button 1 clicked}
    ..process form here..
});
```

would that do it?